# MediaPlayer object stops playing

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having issues with MediaPlayer object in my application for quite some time now. Basicaly what happens is: The sound plays well for some time and then it suddenly stops.
Those are the two methods i use.

```
protected virtual void playMovingSound()
{
    movingSound.Open(new Uri(@"Music\walk.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
    movingSound.Volume = 0.6 * ((GameVariables.ingameSoundOn) ? 1 : 0);
    movingSound.Play();
}

protected void stopMovingSound()
{
    movingSound.Stop();
}
```

I dont understand what the problem is. Even if i call a constructor of MediaPlayer before i play the sound, the problem still persists.

Also other instances of MediaPlayer stop playing at the same time.

The methods stopMovingSound() and playMovingSound() are triggered every second.

Edit1: The class constructor looks like this:

```
protected MediaPlayer movingSound = null;
public PlayerControlledObject(some params...) : base() 
{
    //...
    movingSound = new MediaPlayer();
}
```

And the makeStep method

```
public virtual void makeStep(double stepUnit)
{
    double loopSteps = 100;
    double littleStepX, littleStepY;
    littleStepX = (angle == 0 ? 1 : angle == 180 ? -1 : 0) * stepUnit / loopSteps;
    littleStepY = (angle == 90 ? 1 : angle == 270 ? -1 : 0) * stepUnit / loopSteps;

    Direction currentDirection = getDirection(angle);
    if (!isWalkable(currentDirection))
    {
        return;
    }
    playMovingSound();
    animationRunning = true;
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            for (; loopSteps >= 0; loopSteps--)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    moveTo(GetLeft() + littleStepX, GetTop() + littleStepY);
                }));
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                stopMovingSound();
                fixOffsetAndCenterPlayerPosition();
            }));
            animationRunning = false;
        })) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
}
```

Comment: You need to add more code, like how you initialize the media player etc.

Comment: Well the constructor is really basic (added). The class has a public method makeStep() which is called in a thread and executes playMovingSound and stopMovingSound methods in 1 second delay between them.

Comment: You speak of "instances" of media player, but it looks like you only have one possible instance : `protected MediaPlayer movingSound = null;`

Comment: But i have multiple PlayerControlledObject instances, each containing movingSound.